# ¿Es el SHH mas seguro que HTTPS para enviar commits en github?

Tags: git, github

En el curso de git/github el profesor dijo que SSH es más seguro que HTTPS y no lo dudo porqué lo investigue, pero veo que al configurar la SHH github ya no me pide contraseña para hacer push ¿esto no es peligroso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dos cosas:

- Yo no diría que es más seguro SSH que HTTPS. Ambos son protocolos de transporte cifrados. Durante la comunicación entre cliente y servidor, tanto tus credenciales como los datos del repositorio están a salvo de miradas indiscretas. Usar SSH tiene alguna ventaja, pero también inconvenientes (más adelante me explico)
- No temas porque no te pida la contraseña. Cuando usas SSH tu contraseña de github no juega ya ningún papel, ya que te estás identificando por otro mecanismo, basado en tu pareja de claves privada/pública. No obstante, el hecho de que no te pida ningún tipo de frase de paso, indica que tu clave privada no está protegida, lo que sí puede ser un riesgo (más adelante me explico).

### Sobre SSH frente a HTTPS

Los principales inconvenientes de SSH sobre HTTPS son:

- Es más complejo de configurar (tienes que crear una pareja de claves con `ssh-keygen`, subir la parte pública al servidor, etc)
- En algunas organizaciones el tráfico ssh está bloqueado, y no podrías en ese caso hacer push/pull/clone desde ese sitio. HTTPS en cambio suele estar siempre permitido.

La principal ventaja es:

- No te pide contraseñas, sin que por ello haya riesgo de seguridad **si todo está correctamente configurado**

## Sobre las contraseñas y frases de paso

Cuando te autenticas por HTTPS, `git` te pide tu nombre de usuario y tu contraseña, y envía ambas a Github. Los servidores de Github verifican que ese usuario existe, y que la contraseña enviada es correcta, y entonces dan acceso al repositorio en cuestión.

Esto implica que los servidores de Github tienen que tener guardada de algún modo tu contraseña, para poder compararla con la `git` envía. Esto plantea un pequeño riesgo de seguridad, y es que los archivos donde se guardan las contraseñas de los usuarios puedan ser "robados" por terceros. Usualmente estos archivos no contienen las contraseñas en "texto claro", sino que contienen hashes criptográficos de las contraseñas a partir de las cuales es imposible recuperar las originales, pero un atacante podría dar con las contraseñas de un usuario por fuerza bruta, generando contraseñas habituales, calculando sus hashes y comparando éstos con los almacenados por Github.

En cualquier caso, antes de eso el atacante debería haber conseguido acceso a los ficheros de contraseñas de Github, lo que ya en principio debería ser complejo. El problema aquí básicamente es que *estás confiando en otros* (en Github) para que protejan bien tus contraseñas.

Usando SSH, no necesitas confiar en nadie, porque lo que se guarda en Github en este caso es la parte pública de una pareja de claves, mientras que la parte secreta queda en tu ordenador (y tú eres entonces el responsable de la seguridad de ella). Un atacante que consiga tu clave pública de Github no puede hacer nada con ella sin tener la correspondiente parte privada, que está en tu computador.

No obstante, si el atacante consiguiera entrar en tu ordenador y robara tu parte privada, entonces podría usarla para modificar tus repositorios, leerlos, cambiarlos o borrarlos. Para protegerte de esta eventualidad, cuando creas la pareja de claves con `ssh-keygen` debes suministrar una **frase de paso**. Esta frase de paso se usa para proteger la parte privada de la clave. Gracias a ella, aún si un atacante te roba el archivo con la parte privada de la clave, no podrá usarlo sin conocer la frase de paso, y esta *no está almacenada en ningún lugar*, salvo en tu cabeza.

Naturalmente, usar una frase de paso para proteger la parte privada es lo recomendable. Pero al hacerlo perdemos una de las ventajas de usar ssh, y es la de que no nos pida la contraseña. Fíjate que te pediría una, si bien no sería tu contraseña de github, sino la frase de paso que protege tu clave privada. Si te resulta molesto tener que teclear esa frase de paso cada vez que haces push/pull, puedes usar un **agente** (`ssh-agent`) que es un proceso que mantiene en RAM tu clave privada, y que te pide la frase de paso una sola vez y luego la recuerda.

**Nota final** Aún usando SSH para tus comunicaciones con Github a través del comando `git`, no evitas tener una contraseña en Github, ya que esta la necesitas de todas formas para acceder a través de su interfaz Web. La única forma de evitarlo es registrarse en Github usando algún proveedor OAuth, como Google. En ese caso Github no necesita mantener ninguna contraseña tuya (pero la mantendrá Google, al final en alguien tienes que confiar).

Comment: A mi no me pedia contraseña ya que por motivos de aprendizaje no configure una frase para mis llaves.

Comment: Si quieres mayor seguridad, puedes borrar la pareja de claves generada, generar una nueva (con frase de paso esta vez, pero cuidado no la olvides, no hay forma de recuperarla), y subir a github la nueva clave pública. Github te permite tener muchas claves públicas (correspondientes a otras tantas claves privadas) para que te autentiques con cualquiera de ellas (por ejemplo, desde diferentes ordenadores).